# pythagorean triangle with any side equal to zero

Tags: ruby

So I have this spec I'm trying to solve for (I did not write the spec)...

```
  it "returns false if any of the arguments are 0" do
    # [0, 1, 1].permutation(3) returns all permutations of [0, 1, 1]
    length = rand(0.01..100.0)
    [0, length, length].permutation(3).all? { |(a,b,c)| valid_triangle?(a,b,c) }.should be_false
  end
```

Here is my code

```
def valid_triangle?(a, b, c)
#A Pythagorean triple consists of three positive integers a, b, and c, such that a2 + b2 = c2.
  if a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0
    one   = a**2
    two   = b**2
    three = c**2
    if one+two=three
      return "true"
    else
      return "false"
    end
  else
    return "false"
  end
end
```

How can I pass my spec? What am I missing?

Comment: This is probably related to floating-point imprecision. Try to convert the parameters to `BigDecimal` before multiplication.

Comment: You should probably rename your method, `valid_right_triangle?`, or better, just `right_triangle?`. btw, I'm curious: what are looking at out of the corner of your eye?

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that when the test permutes the values of `a`, `b` and `c`, your method is not always checking that it is the square of the hypotenuse that equals the sum of the squares of the other two sides.  For example, if `a=3`, `b=4` and `c=5`, one of your tests will be `4*4 + 5*5 == 3*3`.  You need to sort `a`, `b` and `c` before checking the sum of squares, which is a good idea anyway, since the position of the hypotenuse among the parameters is not guaranteed.  You could also simplify your code somewhat.  Here's one way you could write it:

```
TOLERANCE = 0.01

def right_triangle?(a, b, c)
  return false if  a == 0 || b == 0 || c == 0
  a, b, c = [a,b,c].sort
  (a**2 + b**2 - c**2).abs < TOLERANCE
end

length = rand(0.01..100.0)
[0.0, length, length].permutation(3).all? { |(a,b,c)| right_triangle?(a,b,c)}
  #=> false

[3,4,5].permutation(3).all? { |(a,b,c)| right_triangle?(a,b,c) }
  #=> true
```

Since you are dealing with floats, you need to establish some level of tolerance when comparing values for equality.  I've used an arbitrary fixed amount (`0.01`) for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning `"false"` and `"true"` instead of `false` and `true`, also you check that `one+two=three`, when you should check `one+two==three` (an equals check, not an assignment)

```
def valid_triangle?(a, b, c)
#A Pythagorean triple consists of three positive integers a, b, and c, such that a2 + b2 = c2.
  if a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0
    one   = a**2
    two   = b**2
    three = c**2
    if one+two == three
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  else
    return false
  end
end
```